# Dose 'parent template' means 'parent component ' in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Dose **"parent template"** means **"parent component "**  in Vue?

In this pic I feel confused about that.Our country tranlator tranlate both the same thing, I don`t kown whether or not right.

[image]

Comment: Simply, *"template"* always refers to the [`template` property](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#template) of a Vue instance or component. A *"component"* refers to an actual [Vue component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

Comment: @Phil thanks a lot .I will read it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component is more than just a template...it is a holistic encapsulation of a template, the local scope, the logical methods, and the style (particularly when scoped).

In this particular case, the template is useful for creating a ***visual reference*** of the bounds of the component, since it is easy to quantify.  For all intents and purposes you can treat them as the same for this piece of documentation, although it is important to understand the technical difference between the two.